# Filter posts by tax (dropdown) and meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, post-meta

I'm having a page on which all my custom post types are displayed.
I now need to add another to the existing ones:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'bkroadkill',
    'post_status'    => 'publish, future',
    'posts_per_page'    => '15'
);

if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  && isset($_POST['filterform']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['filterform'],'filterform') )
{       
        if (isset($_POST['own']) && !empty($_POST['own'])){
            $args['author'] = get_current_user_id();
        }
        if (isset($_POST['comments']) && !empty($_POST['comments'])){
            $args['orderby'] = 'comment_count' ;
        }           
}
query_posts( $args );
```

This is working perfeclty fine.
What I want to do now is add these filters

- Filter by selecting one or more categories from `wp_dropdown_categories` of my custom taxonomy
- Filter by meta value which is already set

For all of the filters except the category simple checkboxes are used. I just check if they are set and when they are I change my string.

My attempts for the other 2 filters failed:

```
    if (isset($_POST['cat']) && !empty($_POST['cat'])){
        $args['roadkill_category'] = $_POST['cat'];
    }
```

As I am very new to wordpress even this simple stuff is confusing me

**EDIT:**

I was able to create the filter for my meta value now:

```
if (isset($_POST['bestimmung']) && !empty($_POST['bestimmung'])){   
        $args['meta_query'] = array(array(
                                            'key'     => 'bestimmung',
                                            'value'   => 'nein',
                                            'compare' => 'IS'
                                        ));
    }
```

So I'm just missing the filter for the custom taxonomy.

Comment: you can't mix querystring and array arguments, see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for proper argument formatting.

Comment: I tried it with WP_Query before and wasn't able to access any of my post meta in the loop then. Also it would be easy to combine the string like this if several options are picked. How could i achieve that using WP_Query?

Comment: Could you change the code to use the `WP_Query` then paste here? So we can figure out why you can't get your post meta.

Comment: I will give it a try now with using $args array codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts see last example. Can I use array_push to add values from my form?

Comment: I updated my question, I guess I am heading in the right direction.

Comment: The best practice is not to use `query_posts` to change the default query on a page, even the result is the same with `WP_Query`. Please refer to [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: As I want to keep it simple I just can use `get_posts()` instead of query_posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the taxonomy query in your case, the code would be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['cat']) && !empty($_POST['cat'])){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'roadkill_category',
            'field' => 'id', // or slug
            'terms' => $_POST['cat'],
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    );
}
```

If you have further questions about tax query, please refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: Works like a charm. Except you forgot a semicolon ;)
Thanks a lot for this. And should I use `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()`? I tried it and I get very strange resuluts (only one of 3 posts coming up and no meta data available)

Comment: Okay I'm wrong, I'm not able to select multiple categories from my dropdown. I just used to jQuery to make my select accept multiple choices: `jQuery("#cat").attr( 'multiple', 'multiple' );`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you fixed the first issue, the second one is in the same vein, as is described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19913/how-to-create-a-wp-query-that-contains-both-meta-query-and-tax-query).

```
$args['tax_query'] = array( array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'custom-taxonomy',
        'field'     => 'id',
        'terms'     => $term_id,
        'operator'  => 'IN'
    )
);
```